# Dropbox like syncing for Google Docs

Tags: macos, sync, software-rec, google-docs, dropbox

Is their a way (on mac osx) to sync a folder on my computer with Google Documents now that Docs supports all file types?

A lot like the functionality of DropBox.

Comment: Not natively. There might be a third-party solution but I highly doubt it. Why not just use Google Docs? Or if it's the syncing that you need, why not simply use Dropbox?

Answer (score 5):

Google has implemented that feature. Try [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com/start).

Answer (score 3):

This is currently only supported if you have Google Apps Premier Edition using the Google Documents List Data API.

There are 3rd parties that have created applications implementing the functionality:

One for Mac is: [Memeo Connect](http://www.memeoconnect.com/)

More info: [Store and share files in the cloud with Google Docs](http://googleenterprise.blogspot.com/2010/01/store-and-share-files-in-cloud-with.html)

Answer (score 1):

There may be some workarounds, but here is a request link for dropbox to add functionality to their product to sync with Google Docs: http://getsatisfaction.com/dropbox/topics/sync_dropbox_with_google_docs

Answer (score 1):

I spent the afternoon fighting with [CyberDuck](http://www.cyberduck.ch/) on my Macbook, trying to get it to sync Google Docs to a local directory.

I was trying to use synchronize and it would choke after doing a few files on the "mirror" setting.   I wanted to preserve time settings on the files.  Eventually I conceded defeat.

I tried downloading from Google Docs itself but you get a bunch of files without the collection labels and the time is set to Jan 1 1980.

I tried an extension for Google Chrome but although the extension was free, you only got 15 days of free syncing before you have to pay $5/month.

The best free solution I found was to use [Syncplicity](https://my.syncplicity.com/Signup/UserSignup.aspx?plan=free&token=QOTAPEUL)  It's got a limit of 2GB but since a couple of hundred of my files totals up to 21MB, I'm not too worried about that. It's also got a limit of 2 devices that can sync.   For me, that's not an issue right now.   My use case is wanting to have things in Google Docs that I can work on when I'm not connected to the internet.

I'd prefer to not use a third-party service and would like a Dropbox-like solution from Google itself.  Which there are rumors about but so far hasn't happened.

The link to Syncplicity has my referral code in it but I'm not affilated with it otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

For Mac you can try: http://gosyncapp.com/ that allows drop-box like sync for mac and google docs.

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://www.insynchq.com

it's fantastic and will do exactly what you need to, access your google docs from your desktop/non browser.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need extra clients when the functionality is already there: access your Google Drive files through WebDAV using OS X’s built-in WebDAV capabilities.
Use the online service provided by [synqya](http://synqya.appspot.com) for the WebDAV access, then use the “Connect to Server…” option from the “Go” menu in the Finder, enter connection details and once you have an authenticated server connection, it will mount a network drive on your desktop.